# Styled checkboxes script

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm looking for a script that allows me to have multiple images (could be icons as well).
Once someone clicks the the image / icon it becomes a different color. Only one image / icon can be highlighted at the same time.

Why do I need this?
I need a form with multiple categories. Each image / icon represents a category. When submitting the form I need to have the value of the highlighted image / icon.

I guess the form would need checkboxes with some kind of css hiding the checkbox itself and showing an image / icon in stead?
Could someone help me out with this? Not a clue how to start...

Comment: Don't you mean a radio input instead of checkbox since you want only one image highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the image and input in a label like so:

### Small example

```css
label img { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="img" value="image_id_or_path" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="img" value="image_id_or_path" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</label>
```

And if we use some jQuery to display the selected image you could use something like:

### Working example

```js
$( function() { 
 $( 'label input' ).on( 'change', function() {
  $( 'img.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
  $( this ).parent().find( 'img' ).addClass( 'active' );
 } )
} );
```

```css
label img { cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid transparent; }
label input[type="radio"] { display: none; }
img.active { border: 1px solid blue;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="img" value="image_id_or_path" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="img" value="image_id_or_path" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</label>
```